# How do I make libtool honour installation prefix?

Tags: debian, make, libtool

I'm trying to build and install the PDF viewer Atril from source in the directory `$HOME/.local` on a computer running Debian 10. I have issued the commands

```
cd "$HOME/.local/src"
apt source atril
cd atril-1.20.3
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix="$HOME/.local"
make
make install
```

The last command fails with the error message

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libatril-properties-page.soT /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/caja/extensions-2.0/libatril-properties-page.so
/usr/bin/install: cannot remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/caja/extensions-2.0/libatril-properties-page.so': Permission denied
```

because libtool tries to install a library under `/usr/lib`. Is there an option I have missed here to make libtool honour the prefix `$HOME/.local`?

Comment: ./configure requires a full path: `./configure --prefix=/home/name/.local`

Comment: @KnudLarsen The environment variable `$HOME` expands to a full (absolute) path.

Comment: What if you execute `make clean && make && make install`?

Comment: @GAD3R I have tried `make clean` as well. I get the same error.

Comment: It appears that `configure.in` is hard-wired to use `pkg-config --variable=extensiondir libcaja-extension` to determine the destination for caja extensions

Comment: @steeldriver I assume you mean in `configure.ac` since I find no file named `configure.in`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom oops sorry yes I did mean `configure.ac`

Answer (score 3):

`atril` needs a place where to put the extensions for the [caja file manager](https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja).

You can change the path in the makefile:

```
cajaextensiondir =
```

Or you can disable `caja-extensions` if you are not using them:

```
./configure --prefix="$HOME/.local" --disable-caja
```

Note that it will build and install, but in order to run, it also needs to find some `mate` stuff (that you might have already available).

Comment: I tried replacing `/usr` with `/home/august/.local` in the path defined by *cajaextensiondir* in Makefile but it made no difference. I get the same error message. Obviously it's ignored by the install command.

Comment: With the option `--disable-caja` I can successfully install Atril.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the conclusion is that there is a flaw in the Atril build script since it should be possible to install any package locally in the home directory (without root privileges). It would be nice if there was an automated test which prevents packages to enter the debian repository unless this requirement is met.

Comment: The reason I want to build Atril from source is because since a week ago or so it takes 25 seconds to launch Atril (with no document) when it used to open instantly. Now I'm trying to find out what causes the delay. When I open Atril built from source I get the same delay, so I'm good to go even without caja.